# How to determine if exception was caused by a specific other exception?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, exception

Elastic search throws RemoteTransportException that is caused by IndexAlreadyExists exception.

I would like to ignore this one case, but still make sure to catch any other exceptions that might occur.

To that end, I implemented a function to determine if an exception was caused by another exception:

```
  private def exceptionCausedBy[T](e: Throwable): Boolean = {
    // scalastyle:off null
    e.isInstanceOf[T] || (e.getCause != null  && exceptionCausedBy[T](e.getCause))
  }
```

which I call like so:

```
...
case e: Throwable if exceptionCausedBy[IndexAlreadyExistsException](e) =>
...
```

This, however gives warning:

```
abstract type T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure 
e.isInstanceOf[T] || (e.getCause != null  && exceptionCausedBy[T](e.getCause))
              ^
```

Which makes sense, because the type T is known at compile time and erased by the compiler.

Is it sufficient to add ClassTag like so?

```
def exceptionCausedBy[T: ClassTag](e: Throwable): Boolean = {
  // scalastyle:off null
  e.isInstanceOf[T] || (e.getCause != null  && exceptionCausedBy[T](e.getCause))
}
```

My testing in IDEA Scratchfile seems to confirm this, but I would like to get some expert opinion.

Also if this is a totally stupid way of going about this, please don't hesitate to point it out :)

Comment: At least It sounds logical :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isInstanceOf[T]` check doesn't use `ClassTag`, matching `: T` does. So it should be

```
def exceptionCausedBy[T: ClassTag](e: Throwable): Boolean = e match {
  // scalastyle:off null
  case null => false
  // scalastyle:on null
  case _: T => true
  case _ => exceptionCausedBy[T](e.getCause)
}
```

Comment: Great, that seems to do the trick. Can you help me understand what exactly is the role of the `:Classtag` here?

Comment: Search for "Scala context bound", there are a lot of explanations (both on SO specifically and on Internet in general).

Comment: you can add `@tailrec` to improve performance as well

Comment: @jjuraszek `@tailrec` won't improve performance (unless it's changed since the last time I've learned it). If the function is already tail-recursive it will be compiled in the same way and so have the same performance, if it isn't, `@tailrec` will fail compilation. However, in this case it might give a hint that the method needs to be final (depends on where it is declared) to be tail-recursive and _this change_ will improve performance.